# webpack3 query string in dynamic require? Or single file, multiple outputs?

Tags: webpack, query-string, require

I'm writing an image processing loader for webpack. I'd like for my loader to be very simple and generic so that it can easily be chained with other loaders: input an image, run the image through a bunch of operations based on loader configuration (resizing, converting, etc), output an image.

In my use-case, I want to use this loader to create multiple versions of a single image, for example: different sizes for a responsive layout; webp versions for browsers that support them; etc.

One way this might work is using the `resourceQuery` test in my webpack config rules:

```
...
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jpe?g$/,
    oneOf: [
      {
        resourceQuery: /webp/,
        loaders: [
          'file-loader',
          /* configure my loader to generate webp files */
        ]
      },
      {
        resourceQuery: /size1024/,
        loaders: [
          'file-loader',
          /* configure my loader to resize to a width of 1024 */
        ]
      },
      // etc...
      {
        /* no resourceQuery - default processing for an image */
        loaders: [ 'file-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
...
```

This works if I use `import` to convert an image:

```
import webpImage from '../assets/image.jpg?webp'
```

But, say I have my images in an array so I want to `require` them... This works:

```
images.map(path => require(`../assets/${path}`))
```

But adding a query string does *not* seem to work ("cannot find module" is the error):

```
images.map(path => require(`../assets/${path}?webp`))
```

Is there some magical webpack incantation to do something like this? I'm open to other suggestions to accomplish my goal. For example, I've thought about using multi-loader to only require the image once without any query string, but multi-loader only exports the result of the last loader. If it exported an array or some kind of key/value hash of the results from all the loaders, that might work, but it doesn't.